# Should I use new activity or a fragment for scanning a barcode?

Tags: android, android-fragments, zxing

I have an activity were the user should be able to enter 2 parameters by writing them or by using a barcode scanner by clicking on the button beside the edittext.

[image: ConfigActivity]

For the scan I will use zxing, because I can find many useable examples with it. After the scan the scanned value should be written in the editbox for the user.

My problem is that I don't know if I should use fragments or a new activity because I will need to communicate with it.

A fragment would make sense, because I want to cover the whole screen with the camera/scanner, but is it recommendable to switch between 2 whole screen fragments?

And if I should use fragments, what would be the best way to do it for this case?

Example of xzing as fragment:

```
public class FullScannerActivity extends BaseScannerActivity implements MessageDialogFragment.MessageDialogListener,
    ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler, FormatSelectorDialogFragment.FormatSelectorDialogListener,
    CameraSelectorDialogFragment.CameraSelectorDialogListener {
private static final String FLASH_STATE = "FLASH_STATE";
private static final String AUTO_FOCUS_STATE = "AUTO_FOCUS_STATE";
private static final String SELECTED_FORMATS = "SELECTED_FORMATS";
private static final String CAMERA_ID = "CAMERA_ID";
private ZXingScannerView mScannerView;
private boolean mFlash;
private boolean mAutoFocus;
private ArrayList<Integer> mSelectedIndices;
private int mCameraId = -1;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
    super.onCreate(state);
    if(state != null) {
        mFlash = state.getBoolean(FLASH_STATE, false);
        mAutoFocus = state.getBoolean(AUTO_FOCUS_STATE, true);
        mSelectedIndices = state.getIntegerArrayList(SELECTED_FORMATS);
        mCameraId = state.getInt(CAMERA_ID, -1);
    } else {
        mFlash = false;
        mAutoFocus = true;
        mSelectedIndices = null;
        mCameraId = -1;
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_simple_scanner);
    setupToolbar();

    ViewGroup contentFrame = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
    mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);
    setupFormats();
    contentFrame.addView(mScannerView);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mScannerView.setResultHandler(this);
    mScannerView.startCamera(mCameraId);
    mScannerView.setFlash(mFlash);
    mScannerView.setAutoFocus(mAutoFocus);
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putBoolean(FLASH_STATE, mFlash);
    outState.putBoolean(AUTO_FOCUS_STATE, mAutoFocus);
    outState.putIntegerArrayList(SELECTED_FORMATS, mSelectedIndices);
    outState.putInt(CAMERA_ID, mCameraId);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuItem menuItem;

    if(mFlash) {
        menuItem = menu.add(Menu.NONE, R.id.menu_flash, 0, R.string.flash_on);
    } else {
        menuItem = menu.add(Menu.NONE, R.id.menu_flash, 0, R.string.flash_off);
    }
    MenuItemCompat.setShowAsAction(menuItem, MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_NEVER);


    if(mAutoFocus) {
        menuItem = menu.add(Menu.NONE, R.id.menu_auto_focus, 0, R.string.auto_focus_on);
    } else {
        menuItem = menu.add(Menu.NONE, R.id.menu_auto_focus, 0, R.string.auto_focus_off);
    }
    MenuItemCompat.setShowAsAction(menuItem, MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_NEVER);

    menuItem = menu.add(Menu.NONE, R.id.menu_formats, 0, R.string.formats);
    MenuItemCompat.setShowAsAction(menuItem, MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_NEVER);

    menuItem = menu.add(Menu.NONE, R.id.menu_camera_selector, 0, R.string.select_camera);
    MenuItemCompat.setShowAsAction(menuItem, MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_NEVER);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle presses on the action bar items
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_flash:
            mFlash = !mFlash;
            if(mFlash) {
                item.setTitle(R.string.flash_on);
            } else {
                item.setTitle(R.string.flash_off);
            }
            mScannerView.setFlash(mFlash);
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_auto_focus:
            mAutoFocus = !mAutoFocus;
            if(mAutoFocus) {
                item.setTitle(R.string.auto_focus_on);
            } else {
                item.setTitle(R.string.auto_focus_off);
            }
            mScannerView.setAutoFocus(mAutoFocus);
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_formats:
            DialogFragment fragment = FormatSelectorDialogFragment.newInstance(this, mSelectedIndices);
            fragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "format_selector");
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_camera_selector:
            mScannerView.stopCamera();
            DialogFragment cFragment = CameraSelectorDialogFragment.newInstance(this, mCameraId);
            cFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "camera_selector");
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
public void handleResult(Result rawResult) {
    try {
        Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notification);
        r.play();
    } catch (Exception e) {}
    showMessageDialog("Contents = " + rawResult.getText() + ", Format = " + rawResult.getBarcodeFormat().toString());
}

public void showMessageDialog(String message) {
    DialogFragment fragment = MessageDialogFragment.newInstance("Scan Results", message, this);
    fragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "scan_results");
}

public void closeMessageDialog() {
    closeDialog("scan_results");
}

public void closeFormatsDialog() {
    closeDialog("format_selector");
}

public void closeDialog(String dialogName) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    DialogFragment fragment = (DialogFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(dialogName);
    if(fragment != null) {
        fragment.dismiss();
    }
}

@Override
public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog) {
    // Resume the camera
    mScannerView.resumeCameraPreview(this);
}

@Override
public void onFormatsSaved(ArrayList<Integer> selectedIndices) {
    mSelectedIndices = selectedIndices;
    setupFormats();
}

@Override
public void onCameraSelected(int cameraId) {
    mCameraId = cameraId;
    mScannerView.startCamera(mCameraId);
    mScannerView.setFlash(mFlash);
    mScannerView.setAutoFocus(mAutoFocus);
}

public void setupFormats() {
    List<BarcodeFormat> formats = new ArrayList<BarcodeFormat>();
    if(mSelectedIndices == null || mSelectedIndices.isEmpty()) {
        mSelectedIndices = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int i = 0; i < ZXingScannerView.ALL_FORMATS.size(); i++) {
            mSelectedIndices.add(i);
        }
    }

    for(int index : mSelectedIndices) {
        formats.add(ZXingScannerView.ALL_FORMATS.get(index));
    }
    if(mScannerView != null) {
        mScannerView.setFormats(formats);
    }
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mScannerView.stopCamera();
    closeMessageDialog();
    closeFormatsDialog();
}
```

The xml:

```
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<fragment android:name="com.example.registerbutton.FullScannerFragment"
          android:id="@+id/scanner_fragment"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/actionbar_opacity"
    app:theme="@style/TransparentToolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: I will recommend `Activity` and start it for `startActivityForResult`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend creating a new `Activity` instead of a `Fragment`. You can send data as well as receive data from it.

For sending data you can use `startActivityForResult()` and optionnaly `intent.putData()`.

For receiving data you can then override `onActivityResult()`.

Comment: Thank you, I did not know about onActivityResult() !

Comment: Happy to help ! You can find plenty of documentation about this function